# Error building NextJS with @sentry/nextjs on AWS Amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, sentry

I’m just trying to integrate sentry with NextjS v12 using @sentry/nextjs and sentry wizard, everything is fine on localhost and before integrating Sentry, but when I build the app on AWS Amplify, the build is error when starting SSR build with multiple error regarding Module not found: Can’t resolve ‘webpack’.

What is wrong with the build? Is there any solution for this? I have tried several options like adding target: ‘experimental-serverless-trace’ on next.config.js but no luck.

Appreciate your help!

[image]

Comment: In my case, I finally had to purge sentry out of my codebase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue, which seemed to stem from missing webpack modules. I found the fix was to configure the Amplify environmental variable `AMPLIFY_NEXTJS_EXPERIMENTAL_TRACE` to `true`

Update:
To edit your environmental variables, click on your app > under "App Settings" click on "Environment variables" > click the "Manage Variables" button > "Add Variable"
[image: Environment Variable Shown in UI]

Comment: Can you add the steps to add this env

Answer (score 1):

Amplify doesn't support Nextjs 12 yet. You are going to have to use 11.1.4 You can find discussion on the GitHub issue here:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2343

Can't say if your error is 100% the same but it looks like the "known issue" mentioned in that github issue.

Comment: Actually, having precisely the same problem. I didn't know that AWS Amplify doesn't support `next@12` (more than this, I've been successfully deploying my project on `next@12` for a couple of months), so, thank you for pointing it out. I've tried downgrading to `next@11`, it doesn't quite work yet, but the error message certainly changes, so, probably it's a part of the solution.